# How to assign the object value of WPF_Form2 to WPF_Form1 variable in VB.net using WPF Forms?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, global-variables

How to assign the object value of WPF_Form2 to WPF_Form1 variable in VB.net using WPF Forms?

Please see example below

```
WPF_Form1
lbl_Label_1

WPF_Form2
lbl_Label_2.content = "String value"

Goal:
lbl_Label_1.content = lbl_Label_2.content
```

I want to achive this but I received error message

> Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

Please tell me possible solutions for this problem.

Comment: are they within the same project?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same project

Comment: why don't you add a global module & have all the global variables there.from the forms u can then easily set & get the shared variable.

Comment: I just started learning the VB.NET, can you please show me an example? thank you!

Comment: http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/beginner/Global-Variables.html